# Max number of threads in Reactive Extensions / Parallel Extensions

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, system.reactive

Since Microsoft probably killed all download links to the Parallel Extensions CTP, I am totally lost.

I want to specify the max number of tasks running at a certain time, as I want more threads than processors. Any clue how to do this in RX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the default `ThreadPool` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to specify the [`TaskFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory(VS.100).aspx) used in RX? If so, you can create one with a [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(VS.100).aspx) with an appropriate concurrency level. It's not obvious to me at the moment whether there are "stock" schedulers which allow this, or whether it's hidden away (Parallel LINQ certainly offers "maximum concurrency" options) but that's the general plan.

Of course, if you can't change which task factory is being used, this doesn't help much.

Comment: How can I create a new TaskScheduler? Implement by inheriting the default `TaskScheduler`?

Comment: Inherting default TaskScheduler sucks, as almost everything is private; and I don't feel for rewriting the whole scheduler part.

Comment: @Jan: all you need to do is override the MaximumConcurrencyLevel property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel(VS.100).aspx

Comment: You cannot in .Net 3.5, you are forced to override lots of queue'ing stuff that you cannot redirect to the base class, as it's hidden from the inherited class.