# Parallel For Min and Max Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

With using ParallelOptions, How do i specify the Min amount of threads I want? I've sent Max Degree to 50 but when i look sometimes only 17 are open and it doesn't seem like it goes above that.

Advise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max number of threads in Reactive Extensions / Parallel Extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996298/max-number-of-threads-in-reactive-extensions-parallel-extensions)

Comment: You do not need that many threads unless you also have enough cores to run those threads.

Answer (score 0):

The Task Parallel Librabry will decide how much threads are suitable for a given task on a given machine. So only on very rare situations (very high optimization for a specific and well known target machine e.g.) you should give the TPL some more input for the decision. On most scenarios you are better of leaving the TPL doing it's job on it's own.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting wihtout giving any reason! This way I have the best chances to do better next time...

Comment: What say we know we want exactly a certain number of threads, how do we give the TPL that input?

Comment: @VincentMcNabb As the OP already mentioned, use [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx). This only sets an upper limit, but as the TPL will try to use as much threads as possible, this is very close to what you are asking for,

Comment: No it's not. I said the word "exactly". "Max" and "exactly" have entirely different meanings. I have a particular application that takes 20% longer on a particular operation because the TPL takes its sweet time to ramp up the number of threads.

The answer is "It's not possible with the TPL". The answer is not "use the max". To suit this scenario we need to use a different library.

Comment: Sadly another one downvoted the answer without giving a reason. Please do us all a favour and give us a hint why an answer is bad in your opinion. Only that way I can improve myself and others can learn from it.